# Exclude meta_key from wp_query

Tags: arrays, wordpress

I'm struggling for hours now with the following problem.
What I'm trying to do is **'exclude reduced items from a wp-query array'**

This is the code I allready have:

```
echo View::render('page-home.twig', array(
 'wp_query' => $wp_query,
 'posts' => aviators_properties_get_most_recent(4), 
 'meta_key' => '_property_reduced', 
 'meta_compare' => '!=', 
 'meta_value' => true
   )
);
```

I know that the meta_key and meta_value is right.
The first three lines is a part of the template which I use. So this is right too.
But I'm not sure about the rest.

I tried several alternatives like:
meta_compare IN / NOT IN / EXISTS / NOT EXISTS / = / LIKE

I also tried to put the meta things in an extra array. Like this:

```
echo View::render('page-home.twig', array(
 'wp_query' => $wp_query,
 'posts' => aviators_properties_get_most_recent(4), 
 'meta_query' => array(
        array(
        'meta_key' => '_property_reduced',
        'meta_compare' => '!=',
        'meta_value' => true
    )
   )
  )
);
```

All of this doesn't work. Nothing changes at all.

The page where I'm working on is:[www.theoquaedackers.nl/test](http://www.theoquaedackers.nl/test/)
At the bottom of this page you see 'recent toegevoegd'
In this array I want to exclude reduced items.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Greets Mark

Answer (score 0):

The != for meta_compare looks correct as indicated here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Does the true need to be between quotation marks instead?

For a sanity check, I would also echo the value of "_property_reduced" just to double check the value being stored in the database.

Comment: Hi Phil, Thanks for your reply.
The 'true' between quotation marks means that 'true' is a string. But it isn't. It is the actual term in the wordpress scripts. I tried to put the string "1" as a value, but this doesn't work eiter.

I also looked at the database. There I discovered the '_property_reduced' and 'true' is the right value.
But to be more sure I can echo the values. But I don't know how I have to do this. Can you tell me that?

Comment: ah I see you're using a custom theme.  You may have a better chance of a specific solution to your problem by posting in the theme forum here: http://themes.byaviators.com/forum

Otherwise, you can use this code to output the _property_reduced value:

`$args('posts' => aviators_properties_get_most_recent(4));
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
 while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
  $query->the_post();
  echo "Property Reduced:".get_post_meta($post->ID, '_property_reduced', true)."<br/>";
 }
}`

Comment: Hi Phil. Thanks again for your great reply.
Yes, it's true. I use a theme from aviators. I posted this problem on their forum. They answered once, but that wasn't the solution. After that I didn't get any response for more than a week now. But I'm still hoping they will answer my question. It seems like a little problem with an easy solution. But it keeps me busy for more than a week now.
Unfortunitaly your code gives me a white screen. My knowledge of programming is very limited, so I can't check if the code is right. The opening en closing tags seems right. :)

Comment: ok try adding error_reporting(E_ALL) before the code I sent you and we'll see then if there is any PHP error.

Comment: Hmmm, with the error code I still see a white page. This is the complete code of the (part of the) page I'm working on. (page-home.php)

http://jsfiddle.net/zkN8g/

Comment: ah ok, please put the error_reporting(E_ALL); on line 15 and re-run it.

Comment: I did that. But the screen is still white. Maybe it's because the page does not end with an ending php tag? (this ending tag is on another page)

Comment: ok it's possible then that your query is not returning anything.  

I assume aviators_properties_get_most_recent(4) is a function provided by the theme and for some reason it's not returning any data but without knowing how the theme works, it's difficult to say what the problem could be.

Comment: Hi Phil. Yes, I understand. It's hard to know everything about the theme when you only see one page.
It's true that aviators_properties_get_most_recent is a function provided by the theme. So I cannot change this.
I have to wait for a response from the makers of the template.
Thanks a lot for your great help!

Comment: ok good luck I hope they reply.  If you just put aviators_properties_get_most_recent(4) on a line by itself, it should return a list of IDs.   If it's not doing that, then that's where the problem is.  It's possible that the posts have not been setup correctly in the admin side.